# A calculus exercise in integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

The exercise is as follows:

> Let $f(x)=e^x-\ln(x+1)$ and $g$ a function which is continuous in $[0,1]$. Prove that $\exists \ \theta \in [0,1]$ s.t. $$\int_0^1{f(\sqrt{x})}g(x)dx=g(\theta)\int_0^1f(\sqrt{x})dx$$

I am stuck as we do not know anything about $g$, only that it is continuous. I tried applying the max-min theorem on $g$, so I can say that
$m\leq g(x) \leq M$ and then building the integral. I have also proven that $1 \leq f(x) \leq e-\ln2$ in the interval $[0,1]$. Also, I have computed $\int_0^1f(\sqrt{x})dx=\frac{3}{2}$ but it doesn't seem to be of much help. And I have also tried to approach it in this way $$\int_0^1f(\sqrt{x})(g(x)-g(\theta))dx=0$$
and then breaking up the integral and noticing that it changes signs. But that is not enough to solve the problem. Any insights?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Perhaps I am missing something. By building the inequality I get this expression: $\frac{3}{2}\cdot (m-\theta) \leq \int_0^1 {f(\sqrt{(x)}(g(x)-g(\theta))dx} \leq \frac{3}{2}\cdot (M-\theta)$. The right side of the inequality is positive but the left side is also positive.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I'm not sure if what you've tried will work properly. Instead, I believe there's a simpler way, which only uses that $f(x) \gt 0$, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, $f(x)$ is always positive for $x \in [0,1]$, in particular $1 \le f(x) \le e - \ln 2$, so also $1 \le f(\sqrt{x}) \le e - \ln 2$ in that interval. Since $g(x)$ is continuous on the closed interval $[0,1]$, it's also bounded, say with a minimum of $m$ and a maximum of $M$, as you used. Thus, we then get for all $x \in [0,1]$ that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
m & \le g(x) \le M \\
mf(\sqrt{x}) & \le f(\sqrt{x})g(x) \le Mf(\sqrt{x}) \\
\int_{0}^{1}mf(\sqrt{x})dx & \le \int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})g(x)dx \le \int_{0}^{1}Mf(\sqrt{x})dx \\
m\int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})dx & \le \int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})g(x)dx \le M\int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})dx
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, there exists a $m \le y \le M$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})g(x)dx = y\int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})dx$$

By the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there's a $0 \le \theta \le 1$ such that $g(\theta) = y$, so

$$\int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})g(x)dx = g(\theta)\int_{0}^{1}f(\sqrt{x})dx$$

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was that simple!

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is continuous over $[0, 1]$ which is compact. It implies that $g$ have a maximum and minimum over $[0,1]$. We will call them $g_{max}$ and $g_{min}$.

The thing to see is that $f$ is positive over $[0, 1]$ and therefore, so is $x \rightarrow f(\sqrt(x))$.

We can then deduce,

$$ g_{min} \int_0^1 f(\sqrt{x}) dx \leq \int_0^1 f(\sqrt{x})g(x) dx \leq g_{max} \int_0^1 f(\sqrt{x}) dx $$

So there exists a real $\alpha$ between $g_{min}$ and $g_{max}$ such that

$$ \int_0^1 f(\sqrt{x})g(x) dx = \alpha \int_0^1 f(\sqrt{x}) dx $$

since, once again, $g$ is continuous over $[0, 1]$, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $\theta \in [0, 1]$ such that $\alpha = g(\theta)$, which gives you what you want.

Comment: Note that it seems your answer is basically the same as mine.

Comment: It's the same idea, yes